# how to load the dynamically changed css file

Tags: javascript, css

I created a widget and changed the style sheet dynamically using javascript.
href attribute is updated, but the styles not applying in the html page.

Is there anything i have to do additionally to load the css file..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong version of the module, which, given that the module comes standard with Orchard, means that you've been installing a version from the gallery on top of your existing version. You'll want to restore the version that came with Orchard.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Just copy it back from wherever you installed Orchard. For example, get the srouce package from CodePlex that corresponds to the version you're using. The modules are under the web site's directory under the Modules subdirectory. You can find the same structure under src/Orchard.Web in the source package.